# How I can see all task completions in Rally for my assigned items?

Tags: rally, agile

In rally we have 2 weeks of sprint where we plan a set of user stories. For each story there is usually a Development task and a QA task. I am the QA so I only start when I see DEV task as complete.

But for the user stories in my queue, every morning I have to open up each story and check if DEV tasks is complete for that story. How can I have a view where I can quickly see what all stories in my bucket are DEV complete, any given time

Thanks
Sid

Answer (score 0):

Do the Development Tasks always contain "DEV"?  If so, you could set up a [Custom List app](https://help.rallydev.com/custom-grid) for User Stories on a Dashboard and add a query like:

```
((( Tasks.Name contains "DEV" ) AND ( Tasks.State = "Completed" )) AND ( Tasks.Owner.Username = "user@name.com"))
```

This would show you all of the Stories where this is true.

You could further refine it to show when yours are not done or started as well:

```
(((( Tasks.Name contains "DEV" ) AND ( Tasks.State = "Completed" )) AND (Tasks.Name contains "QA" )) AND ( Tasks.State = "Defined")) AND ( Tasks.Owner.Username = "user@name.com"))
```

It may take a moment for it to load, but hopefully it helps.